# Automatically move replies to folder containing parent email

Tags: thunderbird

The following process quite often happens:

1. I receive an email
2. I move it to a folder for organization
3. I reply
4. The person I replied to replies to me
5. The reply ends up in my inbox

The reply gets placed in my inbox directly, not the folder I moved the original email to. Is there a way to set it up so replies get automatically moved into the same folder as the email they are replies to?

Comment: Questions, 1) In bullet # 3, is the outgoing reply stored in "sent" or the "folder for organization" 2) Couldn't threaded messaging provide a better way of grouping conversations as opposed to folders?   3) Edit your question to include the type of mail account (IMAP? POP, etc.)  4) edit your question to include the version of Thuderbird.

Comment: How many such folders do you have? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing folder, e.g., *Credit Cards*, make a [filter rule](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters) that sends *all* relevant messages (e.g., *sender* in [MasterCard, Visa, Discover, American Express]) to that folder. When a new message arrives, that folder will be highlighted to show the email has already been moved there.

Another possibility is to [group messages by thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/message-threading-thunderbird), effectively putting those in a series of replies in a single folder. Any operation done on the thread, e.g., moving it to inside another folder, affects all items in that thread.

The Thunderbird add-on, [Conversations](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/), can also be used to help sort threads.